# How to convert an array of objects into a mapped object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I convert something like `initialArray` array of JSON objects into `finalObject` map?

```
var initialArray = [
             { id:'id1', name:'name1' },
             { id:'id2', name:'name2' },
             { id:'id3', name:'name3' },
             { id:'id4', name:'name4' }
          ];

var finalObject = {
                  'id1':'name1',
                  'id2':'name2',
                  'id3':'name3',
                  'id4':'name4'
               }
```

Things to consider:

- IDs are strings.
- I tried for in loop - couldn't make it to work - http://jsfiddle.net/5af9R/23/

Any ideas?

Comment: Those are just JavaScript objects, there is no JSON in your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to operate on the objects in your array, not strings containing their indexes in the array.

You should also use a regular for loop to iterate over an array.

Your JSFiddle, fixed:

```
var x = [ {id:'1', img:'img1'}, {id:'2', img:'img2'}, {id:'3', img:'img3'} ];
var resp = {};

for( var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ ){
    var obj = x[i];
    resp[obj.id] = obj.img;
}

document.write( JSON.stringify(resp, undefined, 2) );
​
```

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7ZTT/)

You can loop over the array, and for each object, add a new property to `finalObject` whose property name is the id, and whose value is the name.

```
var finalObject = {};

for (var i = 0, max = initialArray.length; i < max; i++)
    finalObject[initialArray[i].id] = initialArray[i].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`resp[key.id] = key.img;`

You correctly call it key. But you need a value;

`resp[x[key].id] = x[key].img;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var finalObject = initialArray.reduce(function(ret, obj){
  ret[obj.id] = obj.name;
  return ret;
}, {});
```

This solution is specific to the property names for the specific question, but `Array.prototype.reduce` is a function I use all the time for any sort of array iteration that requires a non-array result.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using For In correctly [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5af9R/11/)

```
var x = [ {id:'1', img:'img1'}, {id:'2', img:'img2'}, {id:'3', img:'img3'} ];
var resp = {};

for( var key in x ){
    resp['id' + x[key].id] = x[key].img;
}

document.write( JSON.stringify(resp, undefined, 2) );
```

​

Comment: Just need to remove the 'id'+ part and that's exactly what I needed. THanks!

Comment: When I answered, your question specifically stated that you wanted 'id1':'name1' and that your initialArray = [ { id:'1', name:'name1' } so it needed the 'id' to be prepended. I didn't alter your initial array when I made my jsFiddle ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    var id = 'id' + x[i].id;
    var img = x[i].img;
    resp[id] = img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood correctly you can do something like

```
var x =' [ {"id":"1", "img":"img1"}, {"id":"2", "img":"img2"}, {"id":"3", "img":"img3"}]';
var resp = {};
var json = $.parseJSON(x);
$(json).each(function(i,v){        
    resp[v.id]=v.img;
});

 console.log( resp);
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5af9R/22/)

> you talked about json but in the fiddle you provided there was no json even jquery was not added as a resource so i made some assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Today I was on the same question and I didn't find an answer here, except the answer of @adam-rackis.

The way I found is :

```
var initialArray = [
    { id:'id1', name:'name1' },
    { id:'id2', name:'name2' },
    { id:'id3', name:'name3' },
    { id:'id4', name:'name4' }
],
    finalObject = {};

$.each(initialArray, function(k,v) {
    finalObject[v.name] = v.value;
});
```